# IIS Error: Cannot connect to the configuration database

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-server-2003

After rebooting the Windows 2003 Server with the IIS I receive the follow error message:

> Cannot connect to the configuration database

in the browser. The error occur on different pages and with different clients. that I think it is a server problem.

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

A quick web search suggests that this error message is probably coming from SharePoint Services, and indicates that SharePoint cannot connect to its database.

There seem to be several reasons suggested:

- The SQL database is not running, has been removed, or you otherwise can't connect to it (firewall, login credentials, network failure)
- IIS is running in the wrong mode

The latter could be IIS 6.0 configured for IIS 5.0 compatibility mode, or the application pool configured for 32-bit worker processes on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem, and it did happen just after a windows update, hmm...
First of all, someone (windows update) hade change the user account on the service "Windows Internal Database (MICROSOFT##SSEE)". Changed back to the right account and the WSS started to work, but with an error (Application / error or something)

This new problem was something I just got for free after I hade run the Exchange Analyzer tool and done some modifications to my system, that was recommended by the tool.

If i changed my web.config too look like this (c:/inetpub/wss-dir/web.config):

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I discovered what the problem was, it was a access/security issue. The error message told me:

Access to the path "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8c91a6b5\649b28ba" is denied.

But this was not the hole truth... the access denied was not to the ..\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8c91a6b5\649b28ba folder, it was to the %TEMP% folder, that I hade just moved due to a suggestion from the Exchange Analyzer Tool.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with sharepoint I used this to fix the sql database
http://heresjaken.com/sharepoint-cannot-connect-to-configuration-database-error-after-installing-kb2687442-update-on-sbs-server-2008/